# Simplify a conditional

Tags: java, android, if-statement

So i have an EditText in my app where the user types in an aswer. My problem is that when i check the input and use a conditional to check if it is the correct answer it gets overcomplicated.
Here's my code so you get a better understanding of my question

```
if (cuenta == 0) {
    if (inputbox.getText().toString().equals("Ottawa")) {
        resultadolabel.setText("Correcto");}
    else if (inputbox.getText().toString().equals("Ottawa ")) {
        resultadolabel.setText("Correcto");}
    else if (inputbox.getText().toString().equals("ottawa")) {
        resultadolabel.setText("Correcto");}
    else if (inputbox.getText().toString().equals("ottawa ")) {
        resultadolabel.setText("Correcto");}
    else {resultadolabel.setText("Respuesta correcta: Ottawa");}
}
```

As you can see i ask for the capital of Canada, but i want the user to be able to write the text in 4 different ways (Capital letter w/space at the end, lower case leer w/no space at the end, etc..).
This where my question comes up, is there a way to make some sort of "if (this condition, or this other condition or this other condition etc..)

I really need a way to simplify my code because it will get REALLY long specially with countries with accent and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `equalsIgnoreCase()` and `trim()`, for example:

```
if(inputbox.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Ottawa")){
    resultadolabel.setText("Correcto");
}
```

Comment: What about the accents?

Comment: what do you mean by accents? which accents? can you give an example?

Comment: México (é). Not sure if  "accent" is a real word in English, i speak spanish and i don't really know if that is the correct translation.

Comment: oh yes, it is correct. well if you want to allow user to input _accents_, it will make your code complicated since you will have to check it one by one just like you have done. perhaps, you can provide input mask to user or maybe you can use _drop down list_ option instead of _input text_?

Comment: Is there a way to deny the user to input accents? if not, then i guess i'll have to use the drop down lost or something similar. Thanks, you helped a lot.

Comment: you can use `regex` to validate the input text. fox example,  
`inputbox.getText().trim().matches("[a-zA-Z]*")` will check if the input contains only normal characters i.e _a-z or A-Z_. but still, I prefer drop down list for this

Comment: I found the solution for the accents i was looking for. I'll leave it here in case someone ever needs it.
I just added this 2 lines
    `input = Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD);



    
input = input.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");`

Comment: great. that was much better

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `toLowerCase()` and `trim()`

```
if (inputbox.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim().equals("ottawa"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```
if (inputbox.getText().trim().toUpperCase().equals("OTTAWA")) { ...
```

This would obviously also allow permutations such as "   OtTaWa" and "ottawA", but you really can't afford to check all permutations one by one. Possibly introduce a rule that the first letter must be capitalized?

Note that you don't need to `toString()` the return of `getText()` - it is already a String.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="Ottawa ";
        s=s.trim();
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("ottawa"))
        {
            resultadolabel.setText("Correcto");
        }
            else {resultadolabel.setText("Respuesta correcta: Ottawa");} 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try condition with `trim()` which Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted. and use `equalsIgnoreCase()` which ignoring case considerations.

```
if (inputbox.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("ottawa")) {
                    resultadolabel.setText("Correcto");
} else {resultadolabel.setText("Respuesta correcta: Ottawa");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
if(inputbox.getText().toString().matches("^[oO]ttawa\\s?")){
    resultadolabel.setText("Correcto");
} else{
    resultadolabel.setText("Respuesta correcta: Ottawa");
}
```